# I need to run dbt test for all dependent upstream models of a particular selector

Tags: dbt

How do i run dbt tags and selector together something like below.

`dbt test --select +selector:every_3h,+tag:CT0`

This command is not giving me the required output.

Answer (score 0):

In a best effort to be direct, I believe you are simply using `selector` syntax wrong here.

A selector is by definition a shortcut to a set of critieria.
It should be all inclusive of the things you want to accomplish.

Maybe try something like:

`selectors.yml`

```
selectors:
  - name: every_3h
    definition: 
        method: tag
        value: CT0
        value: every_3h
        parents: true
```

Then, when you run the testing command, you simply indicate the selector:

`dbt test --selector every_3h`

Hope that helps.